# Specify image name in "on the fly" java image generation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, javax.imageio

I have some java code that generates an image from scratch.

I also have a servlet that serves the image according to some parameters (fyi, it is QR Code generation).

I would like to specify a name for this image in case somebody right-click and save it. THe browser currently takes the relative URL as a name (ie, generate), and there is no extension.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks,
Alexis.

Answer (score 1):

Use a nice url to encode your image.
I suppose now you're doing something like

```
generateServlet?product=27&query=5
```

instead, map it to

```
images/qr/product27_q5.png
```

This way, the browser will only see the nice url and propose that as a file name.  It also hides your implementation more.

Just map your servlet to `images/qr/*` and then use a regular expression to extract the actual parameters from the requested path.

You could even generate different image types depending on the extension provided :)

Comment: Can also do like this. 'img/viewcover.jpg?selected=22233' viewcover.jpg map to servlet.

Comment: that's a working way to do it, nevertheless I was thinking about some response headers, or better : imageio metadatas :). Thanks anyway, I will think about implementing that.

Comment: @zawhtut: yes, but then all your images will get the name viewcover.jpg when downloaded.  You want a name that is different, and maybe even somewhat descriptive to the user.

Answer (score 1):

```
    resp.setContentType("image/jpg");
    resp.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + your_filename + "\"" );
```

Comment: +1. Be careful with the name :) Use only ascii-7 or look for reference about how to encode the filename into the header.

Comment: this works for downloading the image, in my case it is display in an <img> HTML tag. I also tried "Content-Disposition", "inline;